# How can an application write text to the screen?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, hook

How can an application write text to the screen without using any DrawText type methods, and how can I catch it?

I've hooked the following:

```
DrawText
DrawTextA
DrawTextW
DrawTextEx
DrawTextExA
DrawTextExW
TextOut
TextOutA
TextOutW
ExtTextOut
ExtTextOutA
ExtTextOutW
PolyTextOut
PolyTextOutA
PolyTextOutW
```

None of them yields a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many applications will write their own proprietary Text Drawing API, for the exact reason that they don't want you to hook it... easily. Take a look at James Devlin's Poker Botting series, he talks about this and how certain poker sites have their own API. He also talks about methods to get around this, OCR, memory scraping.

[Coding The Wheel](http://www.codingthewheel.com)